# How to count the number of class?

Tags: javascript, twig, drupal-8

On my page I have several blocks, some have a class `task-success` and others have the class `task-alert`.

How to add a class `task-alert` to the menu if the class `task-danger` is present in the page ?

I managed to do this with the JS code below. But the class is added to the menu link only if I am on the page (the page containing the `task-danger` class). If I change pages, the class is not added to the menu link.

The goal is to flash the menu link when `task-danger` is present. There may be a way to display the number of class `task-danger`.

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  if ($(".view-boutique-page-liste-des-taches .task-danger").length) {
    $("#navbar-collapse-first .task").addClass("task-alert");
  };

}(jQuery));
```

[image]

The ideal would be to display the number of each class :

[image]

Comment: This wont be possible in pure `twig` though

Comment: What will you do with the information of count of classes?   Have you considered using JavaScript in a Drupal behavior and running this logic in the browser?

Comment: @stacey.mosier how can I do this with JS ?

Comment: @stacey.mosier I updated my question

Comment: `var i = 0; $("#navbar-collapse-first .task").each(function( index ) { i++ });` will give you the total number. But I don't know if that'll work for you.

Comment: On your Drupal site, launch your browser console and type Drupal.behaviors (press enter) to get an output of current behaviors.  Type drupalSettings (press enter) to get the json output of drupal-settings-json.

If you a triggering JS in Drupal 8, you'll need to know when your JS may need to run again.

See here, an example of running your behavior once (myCustomBehavior) or perhaps multiple times when the 'context' changes (myCustomBehavior2)
https://gist.github.com/staceymosier/1de1c81c02fc3e4452ac87fe3e123577